# Publish same app multiple times

Tags: android

I need to publish the same app multiple times with just some small differences (***app name, app launcher icon, colors and images***).

I will configure `Gradle` to have a different `applicationIdSuffix` for each `buildTypes`.

So the apps will have this kind of packages: `"com.appname.app1", "com.appname.appB", "com.appname.app3", "com.appname.app1234", etc...`

Is that allowed from the `Google Play Store` rules?

Comment: You are perfectly fine

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking for legal advice

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can publish the apps by changing there package names.

Comment: This should be comment.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do what you are proposing.  It is against the [Play Store rules](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) to do this.

If they determine you are doing this, your account could get banned, and there is precedence for this.

You really need to figure out how you can target multiple platforms with the same APK.

Here is the specific language from the page:

> Spam and Placement in the Store Developers are important partners in
>   maintaining a great user experience on Google Play.
>
> ```
> Do not post repetitive content.
> ```

Comment: The problem is that I need to target different telephone operators in the same country, not different platforms. Each telephone operator need to have the app branded with different criteria...

Comment: Can you please tell me where exactly this point is highlighted in the Developer Policy center ?

Comment: It was easy to find (did you look?) - here is where I located it this morning - https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/spam/repetitive-content/